# python skips over my second for loop

Tags: python, minecraft

I am using an API to use python code in minecraft. I have two pillars a skinny one and a fat one which both vary in size. I'm trying to make them be built in a square area at somewhat random spots. All of my code works fine until the bottom. It runs the first for loop posting "1 of 20 complete" but then skips over the second and post the "2 of 20 complete" line to the game chat. Why is it skipping over the second for loop?

```
from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft
mc = Minecraft.create()
import random
import time
```

defines how to build the skinny pillar

```
def skinny_pillar(height, blockType):
    global biomex
    global biomez
    y = mc.getHeight(biomex, biomez)
    if (height == 3):
        height = 2
    if (height == 5):
        height = 4

    #Check it won't hit into anything
    count = 0
    block1 = mc.getBlock(biomex - 3, y, biomez)
    block2 = mc.getBlock(biomex + 3, y, biomez)
    block3 = mc.getBlock(biomex, y, biomez - 3)
    block4 = mc.getBlock(biomex, y, biomez + 3)
    while (count != 1):
        if (block1 != 0):
            biomex += 1
        elif (block2 != 0):
            biomex -= 1
        elif (block3 != 0):
            biomez += 1
        elif (block4 != 0):
            biomez -= 1
        else:
            count += 1

    #Base of the pillar
    baseHeight = height
    mc.setBlocks(biomex - 1, y, biomez - 1, biomex + 1, y + baseHeight, biomez + 1, blockType)
    mc.setBlocks(biomex - 2, y, biomez, biomex  + 2, y + baseHeight + 1, biomez, blockType)
    mc.setBlocks(biomex, y, biomez - 2, biomex, y + baseHeight + 1, biomez + 2, blockType)

    #2nd layer of the pillar
    secondHeight = height * 3
    mc.setBlocks(biomex - 1, y, biomez, biomex + 1, y + secondHeight + 1, biomez, blockType)
    mc.setBlocks(biomex, y, biomez - 1, biomex, y + secondHeight + 1, biomez + 1, blockType)

    #Point of the pillar
    pointHeight = height * 6
    mc.setBlocks(biomex, y, biomez, biomex, y + pointHeight, biomez, blockType)

    #Randomlly choose if the pillar will have a rock on top and only put it on the taller ones
    rock = random.randint(1, 100)
    if (height >= 4):
        if (rock >= 70):
            #Layer one
            mc.setBlocks(biomex - 1, y + pointHeight, biomez - 1, biomex + 1, y + pointHeight, biomez + 1, blockType)
            mc.setBlocks(biomex, y + pointHeight, biomez - 2, biomex, y + pointHeight, biomez + 2, blockType)
            #Layer two
            mc.setBlocks(biomex - 2, y + pointHeight + 1, biomez - 1, biomex + 2, y + pointHeight + 1, biomez + 1, blockType)
            mc.setBlocks(biomex - 1, y + pointHeight + 1, biomez - 2, biomex + 1, y + pointHeight + 1, biomez + 2, blockType)
            mc.setBlocks(biomex, y + pointHeight + 1, biomez - 3, biomex, y + pointHeight + 1, biomez + 3, blockType)
            #Layer three
            mc.setBlocks(biomex - 2, y + pointHeight + 2, biomez - 2, biomex + 2, y + pointHeight + 2, biomez + 2, blockType)
            mc.setBlocks(biomex - 1, y + pointHeight + 2, biomez - 3, biomex + 1, y + pointHeight + 2, biomez + 3, blockType)
            mc.setBlocks(biomex , y + pointHeight + 2, biomez - 4, biomex, y + pointHeight + 2, biomez + 4, blockType)
            #Layer four
            mc.setBlocks(biomex - 2, y + pointHeight + 3, biomez - 1, biomex + 2, y + pointHeight + 3, biomez + 1, blockType)
            mc.setBlocks(biomex - 1, y + pointHeight + 3, biomez - 2, biomex + 1, y + pointHeight + 3, biomez + 2, blockType)
            mc.setBlocks(biomex, y + pointHeight + 3, biomez - 3, biomex, y + pointHeight + 3, biomez + 3, blockType)
            #Layer five
            mc.setBlocks(biomex - 1, y + pointHeight + 4, biomez - 1, biomex + 1, y + pointHeight + 4, biomez + 1, blockType)
            mc.setBlocks(biomex, y + pointHeight + 4, biomez - 2, biomex, y + pointHeight + 4, biomez + 2, blockType)
```

defines how to build the fat pillar

```
def fat_pillar(height, blockType):
    global biomex
    global biomez
    y = mc.getHeight(biomex, biomez)
    if (height == 3):
        height = 2
    if (height == 5):
        height = 4

    #Check it won't hit into anything
    count = 0
    while (count != 1):
        block1 = mc.getBlock(biomex - 5, y, biomez)
        block2 = mc.getBlock(biomex + 5, y, biomez)
        block3 = mc.getBlock(biomex, y, biomez - 5)
        block4 = mc.getBlock(biomex, y, biomez + 5)
        if (block1 != 0):
            biomex += 1
        elif (block2 != 0):
            biomex -= 1
        elif (block3 != 0):
            biomez += 1
        elif (block4 != 0):
            biomez -= 1
        else:
            count += 1

    #Base of the pillar
    baseHeight = height / 2
    mc.setBlocks(biomex - 3, y, biomez - 2, biomex + 3, y + baseHeight - 1, biomez + 2, blockType)
    mc.setBlocks(biomex - 2, y, biomez - 3, biomex + 2, y + baseHeight - 1, biomez + 3, blockType)
    mc.setBlocks(biomex, y, biomez - 4, biomex, y + baseHeight - 1, biomez + 4, blockType)
    mc.setBlocks(biomex - 4, y, biomez, biomex + 4, y + baseHeight - 1, biomez, blockType)

    #2nd layer of the pillar
    secondHeight = height
    mc.setBlocks(biomex - 2, y, biomez - 1, biomex + 2, y + secondHeight, biomez + 1, blockType)
    mc.setBlocks(biomex - 1, y, biomez - 2, biomex + 1, y + secondHeight, biomez + 2, blockType)
    mc.setBlocks(biomex - 3, y, biomez - 1, biomex + 3, y + secondHeight - 1, biomez + 1, blockType)
    mc.setBlocks(biomex - 1, y, biomez - 3, biomex + 1, y + secondHeight - 1, biomez + 3, blockType)

    #3rd layer of the pillar
    thirdHeight = height * 2
    mc.setBlocks(biomex - 1, y, biomez - 1, biomex + 1, y + thirdHeight, biomez + 1, blockType)
    mc.setBlocks(biomex, y, biomez - 1, biomex, y + thirdHeight + 1, biomez + 1, blockType)
    mc.setBlocks(biomex - 1, y, biomez, biomex + 1, y + thirdHeight + 1, biomez, blockType)

    #Point of the pillar
    pointHeight = height * 3
    mc.setBlocks(biomex, y, biomez, biomex, y + pointHeight, biomez, blockType)

    #Randomlly choose if the pillar will have a rock on top and only put it on the taller ones
    rock = random.randint(1, 100)
    if (height >= 4):
        if (rock >= 70):
            #Layer one
            mc.setBlocks(biomex - 1, y + pointHeight, biomez - 1, biomex + 1, y + pointHeight, biomez + 1, blockType)
            mc.setBlocks(biomex, y + pointHeight, biomez - 2, biomex, y + pointHeight, biomez + 2, blockType)
            #Layer two
            mc.setBlocks(biomex - 2, y + pointHeight + 1, biomez - 1, biomex + 2, y + pointHeight + 1, biomez + 1, blockType)
            mc.setBlocks(biomex - 1, y + pointHeight + 1, biomez - 2, biomex + 1, y + pointHeight + 1, biomez + 2, blockType)
            mc.setBlocks(biomex, y + pointHeight + 1, biomez - 3, biomex, y + pointHeight + 1, biomez + 3, blockType)
            #Layer three
            mc.setBlocks(biomex - 2, y + pointHeight + 2, biomez - 2, biomex + 2, y + pointHeight + 2, biomez + 2, blockType)
            mc.setBlocks(biomex - 1, y + pointHeight + 2, biomez - 3, biomex + 1, y + pointHeight + 2, biomez + 3, blockType)
            mc.setBlocks(biomex , y + pointHeight + 2, biomez - 4, biomex, y + pointHeight + 2, biomez + 4, blockType)
            #Layer four
            mc.setBlocks(biomex - 2, y + pointHeight + 3, biomez - 1, biomex + 2, y + pointHeight + 3, biomez + 1, blockType)
            mc.setBlocks(biomex - 1, y + pointHeight + 3, biomez - 2, biomex + 1, y + pointHeight + 3, biomez + 2, blockType)
            mc.setBlocks(biomex, y + pointHeight + 3, biomez - 3, biomex, y + pointHeight + 3, biomez + 3, blockType)
            #Layer five
            mc.setBlocks(biomex - 1, y + pointHeight + 4, biomez - 1, biomex + 1, y + pointHeight + 4, biomez + 1, blockType)
            mc.setBlocks(biomex, y + pointHeight + 4, biomez - 2, biomex, y + pointHeight + 4, biomez + 2, blockType)
```

gets the players position which everything is centered around.

```
pos = mc.player.getTilePos()
x = pos.x
z = pos.z
```

I'm splitting the square area (the biome) up into multiple columns. This is the first. The rest would be the same code as this but with slightly different coordinate positioning.

```
#Make the first column of the biome
c = z -50
d = z -40
for i in range(-50, 0, 10):
    a = x + i
    b = x + (i + 10)
    biomex = random.randint(a, b)
    biomez = random.randint(c, d)
    pillar = random.randint(1, 2)
    if (pillar == 1):
        fat_pillar(random.randint(2, 6), 1)
    else:
        skinny_pillar(random.randint(2, 6), 1)
    time.sleep(0.5)
mc.postToChat("1 of 20 complete")
for i in range(50, 0, -10):
    a = x + i
    b = x + (i - 10)
    biomex = random.randint(a, b)
    biomez = random.randint(c, d)
    pillar = random.randint(1, 2)
    if (pillar == 1):
        fat_pillar(random.randint(2, 6), 1)
    else:
        skinny_pillar(random.randint(2, 6), 1)
    time.sleep(0.5)
mc.postToChat("2 of 20 complete")
```

It builds the negative coordinate section of the column (the first for loop) and posts the line to chat. Then it immediately post the second line skipping over the second for loop (the positive coordinate section of the column). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try inserting debug code. e.g. `print("fat_pillar() activated!")`, `print("skinny_pillar successfully created!")`, `print(biomex)` within each function to see if the functions are being activated with the correct values as they should.

Comment: The for loop itself does run so you need to look deeper. You have a great suggestion to add print statements... did that show anything?

Answer (score 0):

So I went around adding text to display for every thing like suggested and found that all the code would work just fine it even went into the start of the second loop up until `biomex = random.randint(a, b)` the text that I added in before that line displayed "got the a 117, got the b 107." From that I realized the problem was the ordering of a and b. In the second loop it makes b the lower number and a the higher one which is opposite from the first loop. For it too work all I had to do was swap a and b in order for the lower number to be first and the higher number to be last `biomex = random.randint(b, a)` I think its weird that python just stopped executing the code their without displaying an error message for me. If it had I probably could have noticed that sooner.